# Odoo Automated Action doesn't run or work

Tags: python, python-2.7, odoo, cron-task, odoo-9

I followed this [demo on github](https://github.com/Yenthe666/Odoo_Samples/tree/master/scheduler_demo) about **automated action in** **Odoo ERP** system and every thing works fine, but the cron job doesn't work or run. I traced the logger and found that there's an

> established connection was aborted by the software hosted on
>   localhost

which is odoo server but I don't know why? I've searched alot about this problem and found no solution, please help

**thanks in advance**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I solved the problem, It was about time zone
when I debugged the source code of **ir.cron** module I found that's it runs cron jobs according to **UTC** time zone, and my computer set to **UTC+2,** so it will never enter the time and will never run.
the solution is to change the time zon of the source code or my computer